# A button from Jumbotron link to a button from navigation bar in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I have navigation in Home, About, Modeling, and Resources. I am wondering how can add a link to a button from Jumbotron that will point to my Navigation.

In App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />  
      <Jumbotron />
      <Layout>
          <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/modeling" component={Modeling} />
          <Route path="/resources" component={Resources} />
          </Switch>
          </Layout>
    
    </div>
  );
}
```

In Jumbotron.js

```
export const Jumbotron = () => (
  <Styles>
    <Jumbo fluid className="jumbo">
      <div className="overlay"></div>
      <Container className="center">
        <h1>Welcome 3D astronomical models</h1>
        <p>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-getStarted" href="#modeling" role="button">Get Started</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-getStarted" href="#about" role="button">Learn More</button>
        </p>
      </Container>
    </Jumbo>
  </Styles>
)
```

I use href="#modeling" but the page does not understand to go to page Modeling
Can anyone help? I am using React

To be specific, look at my code at the link below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-cache-i4xzk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: your code sandbox is displaying `Hello CodeSandbox
Start editing to see some magic happen!` - no jumbotron detected in the output

Comment: could you try again?

Comment: still no output @Sunny - are you editing the correct sandbox? i am looking at `polished-cache-i4xzk`

Comment: try again. it works now

Comment: could you help me how to link the button from jumbotron to the navigation bar About, Modeling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jumbrotron has a CSS issue with regards to `z-index`. The links inside are unable to be interacted with due to the negative `z-index`

```
.jumbo {
  background-size: cover;
  color: #efefef;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: -2; <-- get rid of this */
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

With regards to the button "Learn More", you are using `href` but you can just leverage `NavLink` because you already imported this and already have client-side-routing set up.

Below code should fix it:

```
<NavLink to="/about"><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-getStarted">Learn More</button></NavLink>
```

[image: Edit divine-water-xio1p]

---

At this point I'm not entirely sure where your "Get Started" button should route to but you can follow the same concept I've described above.

Comment: One more thing, do you know how to remove jumbotron except the home page?

Comment: comment out or remove the `<Jumbo fluid className="jumbo">` component (including its children - that entire subtree of components)

Comment: could you go over https://codesandbox.io/s/3d-tool-zjm5m?file=/src/components/Modeling.js here? on Modeling.js, I want to link it into a new page called Upload.js. In a new page Upload.js, I only want to display the navigation bar without jumbotron  "Welcome 3D astronomical objects and get started, learn more button" and whole space left for me to display other things. How can I remove jumbotron in the Upload.js page?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) instead of a button.

Comment: have you tried like this `<Link to="/modeling">Get Started</Link>`?

Comment: What happens when you click the link?

Comment: go over this link to see what I mean https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-cache-i4xzk?file=/src/App.js and could you help me to figure out this?

Comment: I get this error when i try to access the sandbox. Request failed with status code 404. Did you delete it?

Comment: Did you use Link ?

Comment: I used NavLink and removed jumbo css issue

Comment: could you go over codesandbox.io/s/3d-tool-zjm5m?file=/src/components/Modeling.js here? on Modeling.js, I want to link it into a new page called Upload.js. In a new page Upload.js, I only want to display the navigation bar without jumbotron "Welcome 3D astronomical objects and get started, learn more button" and whole space left for me to display other things. How can I remove jumbotron in the Upload.js page?